# error in my android call log app

Tags: android, listview, calllog

I made an Android project out of this code here:[Call history android studio](http://sunil-android.blogspot.ie/2013/09/call-logs-in-android.html)

There were a few bugs I ironed out, like changing paddingbottom to paddingBottom and so on in the activity_main.xml, and now the only problem I'm having is with calldata. Everywhere it comes up in my project, it's in red, and when I put the mouse over it I get, 'cannot resolve symbol calldata'

The only error that's different is when I put the mouse over :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<calldata>{
```

The error is:

```
'getItem(int)' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter' clashes with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.widget.Adapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type
'cannot resolve symbol calldata'
```

In all the other areas in the project where calldata is referenced, namely:

```
CustomAdapter.java :
private List <calldata> listdata=null;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List <calldata> calldata) {
```

and

```
MainActivity.java :
    private List <calldata>list = new ArrayList<calldata>();
```

I get the message:

```
'cannot resolve symbol calldata'
```

Could anybody tell me what I need to add to my code to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where's your `calldata` class? is it `calldata` or `Calldata` or `CallData`?

Comment: It's CallData. I changed it in my source code and now that part of the problem is fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [link you shared](http://sunil-android.blogspot.ie/2013/09/call-logs-in-android.html) the file name is CallData.java, use appropriate file/class name to avoid errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's no longer in red and compiles without errors so correct answer for that. But when I run it now it shuts down instantly and I get the message in logcat :02-11 23:32:54.410  21905-21905/com.example.chris.sunil_gupta E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chris.sunil_gupta/com.example.chris.sunil_gupta.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class linearlayout
Any odea how I could fix this?

Comment: Not sure. Better ask different question with detail and can look at that.